# Loop through not None and not empty directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, directory

Given two directory e.g.,

```
dirA=getTrainingDir()
dirB=getTestingDir()
```

now I want to loop through the two directories if they are not None and not empty string

what I am doing now is:

```
data_directories=[]
if dirA:
  data_directories.append(dirA)
if dirB:
  data_directories.append(dirB)
for data_directory in data_directories:
  ...
```

Any more elegant syntax for this purpose?

Comment: you want to compact your 2 `if`s into a more elegant line, or the `for` loop?

Comment: @CIsForCookies not only that, it is a more general question, any elegant way that can achieve the same purpose

Answer (score 10):

There is not much better way to do this but you can use something like this:

```
if any([dirA,dirB])
```

or:

```
data_directories=[di for di in [dirA,dirB]  if di]
```

Comment: `any([dirA,dirB])` will `True` if any one of the dir evaluates to truthy, but it doesn't tell which one!

Comment: @bro-grammer but you dont need to check all of them if all in `None`.
I said it is not much better, just more better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method:

```
dirA = 'training_dir'
dirB = None

data_directories = list(filter(bool, [dirA, dirB])) # ['training_dir']
```